# Convergence of recursively defined sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was thinking about this recurrence defined sequence-

$a_{n} = \frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}$ for $n \geq 3$

Does $(a_{n})$ necessarily converge? It is just mentioned that $a_{0},a_{1}$ are real numbers

I was thinking how to do this?

Any idea?

Comment: So, each term is halfway between the two previous terms....

Comment: yup it is defined as the new term is half of the sum of previous two terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$2a_n-a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}=0$$

Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving), $$a_n=A\left(-\dfrac12\right)^n+B\cdot1^n$$  where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants

Now $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\dfrac12\right)^n=?$